# Differentiate between pointers and data variables

Tags: c++, pointers

given a function with a variable number of parameters...

```
void function(int count,...)
{
...
}
```

how do i differentiate between pointers and data variables...
given i don't know the types beforehand.
i.e

```
char *p=new char();
*p='v';
function(2,5,p);
```

how to know if p is a pointer so that it can be handled that way inside the function...
i.e if it were a pointer i would use *p else only p etc.
the function to be designed is thus going to be a general function,taking pointers and data ..

any type of answer is acceptable..
thank you in advance...

Comment: Pointer *are* data variables.  I think what you're really asking is how to differentiate between pointers and non-pointers.  (And the answer is, in this context, you can't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using variable arguments. The type of the arguments must be known when calling va_arg.

One possible way to do this is pass pointers to self describing data like [variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Very nice explanation  [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhdxye9(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: but if in the list of parameters were an object then it would be a problem...
as not all types can be given in an union

Comment: I am not sure how right I am ..but why pass the whole object ? You can pass the object data members only to the variable arg list ..right

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.  The variable argument list doesn't have type information.  That is why functions such as `printf` and `scanf` require a format string

```
printf("%s %d\n","here is the magic number",42);
```

You need to either document how your function should be called orr use a format string like `printf` does.

Variable argument list are support in C++ but are not object oriented or typesafe and there are better alternatives.  One C++ alternative is to use a construct such as the `<<` operator as used with cout (the C++ equivalent of `printf`)

```
cout << "here is the magic number" << ' ' << 42 << endl;
```

You can implement this for your own class like this

```
class VarArgs
{
public:
   VarArgs & operator << (int value)
   { 
      //do something 
      return *this;
   }

   VarArgs & operator << (char value)
   { 
      //do something 
      return *this;
   }

   VarArgs & operator << (char *value)
   { 
      //do something 
      return *this;
   }

   //etc.
};
```